# Javascript Click Function Broken in Gallery Script

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a gallery script with JS (I've only been learning for a week so please excuse if I've made any ridiculous mistakes!). When I run the code, I get an error for `controlLeft.onclick = changeImage(--);`, saying `(` is an unexpected token.

By my untrained eye everything should be fine, but evidently not. What have I done wrong here:

```
//Javascript Image Changer

var currentImage = document.getElementById("currentImage");

var imageArray = ["img/1.jpg", "img/2.jpg", "img/3.jpg", "img/4.jpg"];

var imageIndex= 0;

function changeImage(param){
    currentImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex[param];
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length){
        imageIndex = 0;
    }else if(imageIndex <= -1){
        imageIndex = imageArray.length + 1;
    }
}

var controlLeft = document.getElementById("left");
var controlRight = document.getElementById("right");

controlLeft.onclick = changeImage(--);
controlRight.onclick = changeImage(++);
```

Comment: what is `changeImage(--)` supposed to do? This is not valid and I bet is the reason for your error, though it should state `Unexpected token )` and not `(`.

Comment: Yep, as per answers below you cannot pass operators as parameters to a function. Noob mistake, I'm still learning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just pass operators around like other things. Even in a programming language with higher-order functions the same thing usually does *not* apply to operators.

Besides that, `onclick` expects a function - not the result of a function call.

Here's a snippet that is likely to work:

```
function changeImage(mod){
    currentImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex += mod;
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length){
        imageIndex = 0;
    }else if(imageIndex <= -1){
        imageIndex = imageArray.length + 1;
    }
}

var controlLeft = document.getElementById("left");
var controlRight = document.getElementById("right");

controlLeft.onclick = function() { changeImage(-1); };
controlRight.onclick function() { changeImage(1); };
```

Comment: Yep, this got it working. Thanks! So .onclick ALWAYS has to be in the form of `.onclick = function(){}`in Javascript? Couldn't find a good reference out there that didn't use inline javascript on the button itself...

Comment: @Jascination No, not necessarily, if you don't need to hand over parameters, `controlLeft.onclick = changeImage;` (without `()`!) would be okay. But the point is, you need to pass a function or a function reference instead of the *Return value* of a function which would be the case with `controlLeft.onclick = changeImage(-1);`.

Comment: @Christoph But isn't `changeImage()` a function as defined in the OP? In my understanding (which is likely very wrong) your code makes onclick = a function which calls a function...

Comment: @Jascination: That's what you need to do. Otherwise you'd call it immediately and assign its return value as the onclick handler. That would only work if the function returned a function.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Kinda makes sense, seems like I still have a lot to learn with onclick. Do you have any links that explain what you're talking about in more detail? I'm trying my best to learn exactly why things happen in Javascript, as opposed to 'just don't do this', ya know?

Comment: Have a look through the articles in Mozilla's MDN.

Comment: You can pass operators around in Lisp, because these operators are functions. Small example in Common Lisp: `(reduce #'* '(1 2 3 4 5))` gives `120`.

Answer (score -4):

Just make a slight modification:

```
controlLeft.onclick = function() {
    changeImage('back');
};

controlRight.onclick = function() {
    changeImage('forward');
};
```

Comment: That's not enough. `imageIndex['back'];` will still be a no-op.